# Google Analytics data discrepancy between page url and title

Tags: google-analytics

I have Google Analytics on my intranet site.

Doing a search for one year back, when I search for a page URL, I get 1 page view.  But when I do a search for the pages title, I get 142 page views.

What's causing this discrepancy?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#implementation - How are you setting up tracking for your URL and path?  Are you allowing anchors or are you excluding them?

Comment: Maybe the title has changed over time ? Url and title are (independent) hit level dimensions, they do not change backwards in time when the page title is changed after the hit is recorded.

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out. Turns out that there are mutiple pages with the same title!  Which is always bad practice.